# how to connect java derby database in netbeans

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, derby

i have already created the table in connection and table name is "contact db"
i have window where i add detail. Here is the code, i want to add the entered details into my database table 
i dont know how to connect to my table in netbeans, i was able to create the table using an example from netbeans site but connection examples are too fuzzy on net

```
public void addVendor(String nam,String adres,String num)
{
    l1= new JLabel ("Name");
    l2= new JLabel ("Address");
    l3= new JLabel ("contactNumber");
    Name= new JTextField ("");
    Address= new JTextField ("");
    ContactNumber= new JTextField ("");
    b1 = new JButton("Add");

    border = new BorderLayout();
    this.setLayout(border);
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    this.add(Panel);
    Panel.add(l1);
    Panel.add(Name);
    Panel.add(l2);
    Panel.add(Address);
    Panel.add(l3);
    Panel.add(ContactNumber);
    Panel.add(b1);
     b1.addActionListener(this);


     this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(425,325);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent a)
{
    JButton button;
    button = (JButton) a.getSource();
    if (button==b1)
    {
      //here i want to add data to table
    }

}
```

Comment: This may help you [Creating a Java application to access a Derby database](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html)

Comment: this for some reason gives alot of error on net beans

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? What exactly you are facing problem while implementing this piece?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a Derby database in Netbeans, you'll need to know the database name (which you do seem to know), as well as a respective username and password, which you should have needed to specify when you created the database.

You'll also need to know the URL, this is critical. It should be something akin to "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/**YOUR_DATABASE_NAME**"

Also, a quick note, it looks like your database name contains a space, don't ever do that ever. Just call it something like CONTACTSDB or something like that.

Here's something that should hopefully work for you.

```
final String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/YourDatabaseName";
final String databaseName = "NameOfYourDatabase";
final String username = "YourUserName";
final String password = "YourPassword";

// Below is the method invoked to establish a connection to the database
public void accessDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        Class.forName(rolodexDriver).newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, username, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(rolodexBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

} // end of accessDatabase method
```

And then just use the accessDatabase() method and everything should work out, I believe. I hope this helps out.